# Creating a new column by shifting an existing column to 1 row down using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on sport.
The purpose is to record current eventdatetime and PreviousEventTime in a game. I have a sample dataset in the below link.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DUNrWPFwrkZHpq_KeA4rZCJ94sbpUEDI

In this file, there are 11 columns. the event are collected based on time.
For this re-arrange, i will be using the following columns
**gsm_ID**,**eventdatetime** columns

I want to create a new column **PreviousEventTime** that take n-1 row of the **eventdatetime** column.
That means for every **gsm_ID**, there will be the first **eventdatetime**.
The new column will represent the next event time as compared to the time column.

`gsm_ID        eventdatetime            PreviousEventTime`

> `2462794      08/11/2017 18:46         08/11/2017 18:45`
>
> `2462794      08/11/2017 18:49         08/11/2017 18:46`
>
> `2462794      08/11/2017 19:13         08/11/2017 18:49`
>
> `2462794      08/11/2017 19:31         08/11/2017 19:13`
>
> `2462794      08/11/2017 20:09         08/11/2017 19:31`
>
> `2462795      08/12/2017 17:39         08/12/2017 16:30`
>
> `2462795      08/12/2017 17:44         08/12/2017 17:39`

Above example is just for two games. You can differentiate by **gsm_id**. The for row at PreviousEventTime will always be **matchdatetime.**
I will have 100 over games. but the process will repeat as above-mentioned example.

> `eventdata ['PreviousEventTime-1'] = eventdata.groupby(['gsm_id'])['eventdatetime'].shift(-1)`

But it only works for the first **gsm_ID**. It did not work for the other **gsm_ID**.
The output from above script is below:

> [image]

Your advice would be much appreciated.
Regards,
zephyr

Comment: To format the code/data select it and type `ctrl-k`. 
[Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), 
[Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Please reformat the data so we can copy and paste it into our editors.

Comment: For me it working nice, red box is why wrong? Green box is in my opinion wrong, because last row should be missing, not first row per first group. Or need `['eventdatetime'].shift(1)` instead `['eventdatetime'].shift(-1)` ?

Comment: Hi Jez, the new column is the previous event time of eventdatetime column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting properly  solved the problem.
I added in the following sorting and indexing:

> `eventdata = eventdata.set_index(['gsm_id']) .sort_index(ascending =True)`
>
> `eventdata=eventdata.sort_values(['matchdatetime','time'],ascending=[True,True])`
>
> `eventdata ['PreviousEventTime-1'] = eventdata.groupby(['gsm_id','matchdatetime'])['eventdatetime'].shift(1, axis = 0)`

But the remaining part is to fill NaT by **matchdatetime**.
Thanks everyone for advising me.
Regards
zephyr